# Selenium doesn't load the entire page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I guess I'm having a weird issue since I didn't see anyone having an issue like this.

After I click on a button that is supposed to return me a new page, it only returns me the text, no CSS, no images nothing but just text.

I wish I could add a screenshot, but it is an internal tool and unfortunately I'm not allowed to post it.

Have anyone else had an issue similar to this before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: and manual interaction gives different results?

Comment: Yes. I've tried doing the exact same thing multiple times, and it loaded the page perfectly all the time. I've tried different browsers, and never happened when I was trying manually.

Comment: could you give us more info about the software you're using?  Java.  Are you using RC or WebDriver? what version? what browsers? OS?

Comment: +code  .  Is it all sites or just your site?

Comment: @sircapsalot I'm using Java + TestNG and running my test cases from Eclipse. (Not using Grid at the moment) I'm using Selenium WebDriver, mainly Firefox Driver(FF 28) on Windows 7.

Comment: @niharika_neo I haven't tried other sites, but the thing is this only happens on one page. I have 20 test cases, and only this one is having this issue. Think this page as a form, you first submit a part of it, then ajax loads the second part for you to fill. That second part doesn't load completely.

Comment: sounds like you have some firefox settings possibly not letting you.  What you should try, is to set a debug point right before you click the button, then do it manually (using the same browser selenium opened).  If it returns just text, then maybe you should investigate the options you are passing to firefox.  you can limit things like loading images and css.